# Cannot Find Hook that is changing the_content()

Tags: the-content

I am working with a wordpress theme that is using Foundationpress as it's starter theme. When I use `the_content()` all `img` tags have there css class replaced with `image`. This is overwriting the ability for the editors to use there own classes.

While debugging if I `die(get_the_content())` I see the original classes.  I have been going through the entire project trying to find where that logic could be overwriting these classes.  Has anyone seen this before ?

So far i have checked:

1. Functions.php
2. All javascript
3. Library directory that comes with foundationpress.

Anywhere I could be overlooking?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's unusual for `the_content` to be rewriting image classes like this; it sounds like it could be a plugin (or theme function) which is doing this. Have you disabled all plugins just to check?

Having said that, most of the functions in core that hook into `the_content` are located in `wp-includes/default-filters.php` (apart from the oembed functions).

You can remove any of them by adding the following to your theme's `functions.php`, eg. to remove the `wpautop` function:

```
remove_filter("the_content", "wpautop");
```

However none of these should be messing with these classes. The [`wp_make_content_images_responsive`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_make_content_images_responsive/) function *will* be messing with image tags, but it should only be checking the classes, not changing them, which is why it sounds like these changes could be happening in a plugin.

Comment: Turned out to be a plugin.  Responsive Post images

Comment: Glad you found it! I'm not familiar with that plugin, but WP supports responsive images out of the box now so it may no longer be needed?